# Is it possible to resolve named and unnamed unity registration to same instance (ContainerControlled)

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

We know that named registration is resolved using arrays in constructor injection

```
// framework code
var injectionMembers = new InjectionConstructor();
...
container.RegisterType(typeof(Employee), "emp1", 
          new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), injectionMembers); 

container.RegisterType(typeof(Employee), "emp2", 
          new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), injectionMembers2); 
....

// user code
public class Manager
{
    public Manager(Employee[] employee)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am looking to support following, when user knows that their is only one named registration.

```
public class Manager
{
    public Manager(Employee employee)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And to achieve this I thought if there is some way that I can do two registrations, one with name and one without name in the framework code, that could solve the problem.

I can off course do two registrations but both registrations when resolved would give different instances. Is there a way that I can do two registrations, one named and one named which when resolved return the same instance.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here

Comment: If you don't provide a name for a registration, it will not be included in the array. I believe however the unnamed registration would be used when a single object is injected and not an array. Can you try and confirm ?

Comment: @CallumLinington, updated the question, hopefully I am making some sense now

Comment: @FabioSalvalai The registration code is part of framework and does not know how many registrations would be done. Under normal circumstance (when registration and resolve code is written together), I agree with your suggestion

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? I wondering whether this is a x y problem

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to achieve and if it is possible to instantiate the object at this point, you can just register the instance directly:

```
container.RegisterType<MyType>("name1", ...);
container.RegisterInstance<MyType>("name2", container.Resolve<MyType>("name1"));
```

This guarantees that the same instance is registered under both names.